# Sending mail from outlook to linux machine

Tags: linux, email, microsoft-outlook, mutt, sendmail

I am not sure if this is feasible. But, using `sendmail` or `mutt` or `mail` command, I am able to send mail from linux machine to a outlook server.

Whether the vice versa case is possible ? If yes how ?

i.e sending mail to a linux machine from outlook

So that user can read the mail locally in his machine.

**Update :**

Commands I have used,

```
mail -s "Test Subject" dinesh@myofficialemail.com < /dev/null
```

Or

```
mutt -s "Test Email" dinesh@myofficialemail.com < /dev/null
```

I have a linux machine from which if I use the `mail` or `mutt` command to send email to my official email address, then I am getting the mail with the mailing address as

```
dinesh@REMOTELAB; # where 'dinesh' - my username & 'REMOTELAB' - hostname
```

via my outlook.

Now, if I  try replying back to the above email, then I am getting the Underliverable email response from the outlook.

What should I do/configure, so that by sending mail to `dinesh@REMOTELAB`, it could get delivered to my linux machine ?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 : Sorry. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only the same way you'd actually send from a linux machine.

When you are sending mail from a linux machine, it's still going via a mail server, and gets delivered to the recipient.

Why would you think you can't do exactly this in outlook, it's what people do every day.